Question about hyperstandard von Neumann algebras and selfpolar cones
Consider the following fragment from the book "Lectures on von Neumann algebras" by Stratila and Zsido, second edition:

I have two questions:
(1) Why is $\mathscr{M}_q= q\mathscr{M}q \subseteq B(q\mathscr{H})$ a von Neumann algebra? I thought we needed to have $q\in \mathscr{M}$ for this?
(2) I want to understand the claim that $\mathscr{M}_q$ is hyperstandard, but I have trouble verifying condition $(3)$. I have to show that if $x\in \mathscr{M}$ and $\xi \in \mathfrak{B}$, then
$$qxqJqxqJq\xi \in q\mathfrak{B}.$$
I am not sure why this is true. Obviously, we want to somehow invoke $(3)$ for the cone $\mathfrak{B}$.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Does the book comment on the use of the word "hyperstandard"? This is just Haagerup's standard form, I see nothing "hyperstandard" about it.

@MaoWao Standard in the book means the existence of a conjugation $J: \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ such that $M\to M': x \mapsto Jx^J$ defines  an anti-$$-isomorphism that acts identical on the center (see 6.9 in the book). I don't think however, this terminology is standard (pun intended).

For (1), note that we have both $eMe$ is a vNa in $B(eH)$ whenever $e$ is a projection in $M$, and whenever $e$ is a projection in $M’$. Note that $q = e(JeJ)$ and $JeJ \in M’$, so $eMe$ is a vNa in $B(eH)$, but then $e(JeJ) = e(JeJ)e$ is a projection in $eM’e$, which is the commutant of $eMe \subset B(eH)$. Thus, $qMq = [e(JeJ)e]eMe[e(JeJ)e]$ is a vNa in $B([e(JeJ)e]eH) = B(qH)$.
For (2), let $x \in M$, $\xi \in \mathfrak{B}$, then,
$$\begin{split}
qxqJqxqJq\xi &= qxe(JeJ)Je(JeJ)xe(JeJ)Je(JeJ)\xi\\
&= qxe(JeJ)eJxe(JeJ)eJ\xi\\
&= qxeJexeJe\xi\\
&= q(exe)(JexeJ)\xi\\
&\in q\mathfrak{B}
\end{split}$$
Where the final inclusion used that $exe \in M$, so $exe(JexeJ)\xi \in \mathfrak{B}$.
